# Can't run cordova run android in Ionic project

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm having an issue running `cordova run android` in my Ionic project. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Cordova, Ionic, Gradle, and Android Studio, yet I still get this following error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

  > Script 'path/platforms/android/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/app-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle' line: 11
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Could not read script 'path/platforms/android/app/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/properties.gradle' as it does not exist.

**Question: How can I get this error to go away and my project to run successfully?**

Comment: Are you sure that you have that file in your path?? Look at the `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` folder in your project.

Comment: Yep, I have that folder and file in my project

Comment: what version of ionic are you using?

Comment: I'm currently on 3.9.2

Comment: Can you show the `properties.gradle` property?

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075005/cordova-build-android-only-displays-paths-and-does-not-build-the-project-itself/48077818#48077818, it's not exactly the same, but the main problem is an incompatibility in the plugin and cordova-android 7

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: did you solve this issue??