# Cordova build android only displays paths and does not build the project itself

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am trying to build a Cordova app with few plugins ([InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/), [Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), [File Transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html), [Text-to-Speech](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts), [Document Viewer](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer), [GeoLocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html)).

When I run `cordova build android` it only shows the `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` paths but does not build the Android Studio project.

[image: error_screenshot]

I am using Cordova version 8.0.0 and Android `cordova-android@~7.0.0`

Building in the verbose mode gives the following messages

[image: verbose_output]

Comment: try to build like this : cordova build android -- --minSdkVersion 16

Comment: This does not print the `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` paths, only the message `Android Studio Project Detected` is shown.

Comment: @Sumit is your JAVA_HOME pointing to the proper directory?

Comment: @Gandhi Yes, `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly.

Comment: @Sumit Can you create a barebone cordova project and try building android platform first to segregate the issue?

Comment: @Gandhi I tried doing that as told by @jcesarmobile in the reply below but I still seem to be unable to build the project using `cordova build android` for a vanilla project without any plugins.

Comment: @Sumit can you try building browser platform to segregate the issue?

Comment: @Gandhi if I build `cordova build browser` after adding the `browser` platform, then the prompt returns without displaying any message.

Comment: Do you have gradle installed?

Comment: Yes, I was building and running Cordova projects previously without any issues. This seems to be related to updating Cordova.

Comment: @Sumit Is browser platform also fails, then its something to do with cordova installation and nothing specific to android platform